# how to stop htaccess URL redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, url, 301-redirect

I am new to htaccess. so when i want to do a url redirect using htacces, i always get a redirect loop, and don't know how to fix it. I have been searching on the web but coundn't find a solution for me. please help on this

what i want to do is to redirect all the subpages under root(/*) to index.html under root (/index.html)

i need to redirect 
www.mydomain.com.au/*
to 
www.mydomain.com.au/index.html

here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/index.html [R=301,L]
```

please help on how to fix this
thanks very much !!

Comment: please use better output formatting for the .htacess code snippet

Comment: Can you provide either the access log or activity capture from the client browser, showing what redirects are occurring in the loop?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} != http://www.mydomain.com.au/index.html
```

... before ...

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com.au/index.html [R=301,L]
```